# Sub domain file not found

Tags: asp.net

I am making a sub domain. I have made the adjustments to the IIS and get no error with a simple htm page but get this Error.htm?aspxerrorpath=/server/default.aspx when I try to put an aspx page there in the sub folder. 'server' is the sub domain.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell with this little information.  I would say check your event log to see if IIS logged anything as to why it failed.  You could also add a generic logging mechanism to catch any unhandled exceptions and write them out to a log file.  EX:

Create if you do not have already a Global.asax and put something like

```
  Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim err As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
        LogError(err.ToString)
  End Sub
```

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I would say confirm everything in IIS,  Make sure nothing is wrong in web.config, make sure proper .net version is selected in IIS, make sure .aspx handlers are registered in IIS, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The .net framework is fine as the pages load in the root directory fine. Not sure about registering handlers. The IIS is the hosting company's, which I can log into - I very new with all this - any links or help is appreciated. Not sure what I need in the config file - I copied one into this directory - barebones.

Comment: Steps taken: walked thru the IIS url rewrite for the sub domain - they stated it was fine. I created a htm file in server folder - it loads fine. Made a ASPX webform using Right-click on sub domain folder -> add item -> ASPX page. Added a site.master, site.css, web.config for this folder. When the ASPX page would not load I tried putting a link in the htm page to load the ASPX page -> same error. Just don't why this is so hard. I must be missing something simple. I can't seem to get the error logging to work - I will continue to try.

Comment: The hosting company has run some tests and will have to figure out the problem - since they can't seem to see the issue. Thanks for the help and I post back once we get it solved.

Comment: Now they are tell me I have a problem somewhere in the code/markup. How do i add aspx files to this folder correctly?